# How to configure IEDriverServer for testing on IE8

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please, I do automated tests with selenium webdriver Java.

For testing on IE ,I did :

```
**System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                    "C:\\dev\\drivers\\IeDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");

DesiredCapabilities sCaps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            sCaps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
sCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(sCaps);**
```

But, I don't know how to configure all versions of IE (by starting with IE8) ?

Can you give me your advices please ?

I developed this part of code for IE :DesiredCapabilities sCaps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            sCaps.setCapability(
                    InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                    true);
            sCaps.setCapability(
                    InternetExplorerDriver.ignoreProtectedModeSettings,
                    true);
            //sCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(sCaps);

Thanks in Advance,

Kinds Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7

1. You must set Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value.
2. Enhanced Protected Mode for all zones must be same. (I prefer it to be disabled as this is the requirement for IE 10 and higher.)
   Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog.
3. The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.

How to do above steps???

Have look at this video: http://screencast.com/t/5nlxsrje4I . I have showed the steps.

Hope this helps. Thank you :)

Comment: thank you very much I configurate options of IE and my test on IE works but for automating this I should use DesiredCapabilities ? isn't it ?

Comment: I updated the code in my question because I used DesiredCapabilities for IE.Look at the end please.

Comment: You have set the right capabilities @KhalidKsouri . **But the settings which I have told are very important to run your tests on IE.** Please vote up the answer if it was helpful to you. Happy to help :)

Comment: thank you but I didn't find what to use : ignoreProtectedModeSettings with DesiredCapabilities ? because there is no variable for "ignoreProtectedModeSettings ".

Comment: `InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                ieOptions.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
                ieOptions.EnableNativeEvents = false;
                ieOptions.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
                _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieDriverServerLocation, ieOptions, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(tTimeouts))` **This code will help you ignore protected mode settings**

Comment: thank you but the compilator didn't accept this class, It didn't suggested to me "import ....."

Comment: It is available in **OpenQA.Selenium.IE**.

Comment: I have added three dependences into pom.xml : <dependency>
   <groupId>org.testatoo.openqa</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2_20090715</version> and It doesn't work ?? thanks in Advance
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-20080914.225453</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.server</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-20081010.060147</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I have not worked with pom.xml. All I can say is, make sure you use the latest Selenium webdriver. I used 2.45.

Comment: and me too... the dependence is :<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>2.45.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Looks like `InternetExplorerOptions` is not available in java bindings. It works well with c# bindings.

Comment: there is no equivalence in JAVA ? I'm so blocked

Comment: Try this code `public class Sample {
 @Test
 public void test() {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  DesiredCapabilities capabalities=new DesiredCapabilities(DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());
  capabalities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);        
  WebDriver _driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(capabalities);
  _driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");  
  _driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Test");  
 }`

Comment: Thank you I updated my code and it works for the first test case...I will give you a feedback about the others

Comment: Hi Rameshwar, I was absent for one week.This morning I tested all classes with IE and suddenly I received this error message: "Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.41.0.0
Listening on port 17188
avr. 20, 2015 11:55:55 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter extractRemoteWebDriver
AVERTISSEMENT: Augmenter should be applied to the instances of @Augmentable classes or previously augmented instances only".In your opinion What Should I do ? ,Thanks a lot in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run multiple version of IE on the same computer.

The easiest way if you use Selenium Grid, connect Windows nodes to the hub with different versions of IE and you use RemoteWebDriver instead of InternetExplorerDriver.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I use selenium webdriver.what should I do for testing on IE8 only ?

Comment: You must run your tests on a computer where IE8 is installed and also point the **webdriver.ie.driver** system property to the IE WebDriver.

Comment: I tried to download IE8 for windows 7 64 bits but I found just :

Comment: Windows Internet Explorer 8 pour Windows Server 2003 SP2 Édition 64 bits
Windows Internet Explorer 8 pour Windows Vista 64 bits et Windows Server 2008 Édition 64 bits
Windows Internet Explorer 8 pour Windows Vista et Windows Server 2008

Comment: Please, If I use only IE11 what should I do for adapting my code ?